# Working of crontab

Tags: command-line, python, cron

I wish to automate a python script in linux with the help of crontab so that it runs after every 30 minutes. I wrote the following line in crontab :

```
*/30 * * * * python somepath/example.py
```

But it produced an error saying no such file or directory. I had provided the full path to the file.
Next, I tried creating a run.cron file in the same directory as that of the python file and running the file by command : crontab run.cron. The contents of the file is as follows :

```
#echo PATH=$PATH > run.cron
#echo >> run.cron
#crontab -l >> run.cron
#crontab run.cron

*/30 * * * * python fullpath/example.py
```

Still it had the same error. Can someone help fix this issue or suggest an alternate solution to this problem.

Thank you.

PS- This problem is coming even if I am trying to run a cd command. It says No such file or directory.

Comment: A full path would start with `/`. Example: `/home/me/crontabs/example.py`. Consider migrating your scripts to Python3 for future compatibility.

Comment: You need to specify the full path of the `python` binary.

Comment: @user535733 Yes! I forgot to add it while asking the question.

Comment: *What* "says no such file or directory"? you don't appear to redirect your command output or its errors to a file, so where are you seeing this message exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/env python2 /some/path/example.py
```

or

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/env python3 /some/path/example.py
```

Depending on what version of python you are using

Comment: Thanks, but there was a environment problem which I solved and now it is working.